# Regex to remove html tag inside square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used Regex to extract the content inside square brackets :-

```
string.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

but this does not extract the string between square brackets such as

string= "[Description of project (only for)]"

also what will be the regex to remove the html elements inside the square brackets

example :-

```
string="[<span>Description of project (only for)</span>]"
```

output after apllying regex should be "Description of project(only for)"

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: you want it in javascript? or what language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Match all content in square brackets.
2. Use a callback function to replace html tags in this matched content.

## DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/uZRQt/

```
var matches = "This is <span>Outside content </span> and inside is [<span>Description of project (only for)</span>]".replace(/\[.*?\]/gi,function(match) {

    return match.replace(/<\/?[^>]*?>/gi,'');

});

alert(matches);
```

Comment: Hey its not working for something like 

getcontent=<table style="height: 1000px; ; width: 500px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>[<span>Assignment name</span>]</td>
<td>[<span>Total No of staff-months of the assignment</span>]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


in this i dont want to lose any other tag except the ones which are inside the quare brackets

Comment: @user1744639 , It does work for this input as well : http://jsfiddle.net/uZRQt/1/